# how to use pivot wider with different column combinations?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
df <- data.frame(xy=c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), xz=c("D","E","F","G","H","I"), y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

I'm trying to `pivot_wider` the column `xy` with `y` and `xz` with `z` such that the output looks like:

```
y.A  y.B  y.C  z.D  z.E  z.F  z.G  z.H  z.I
3     7   11    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

There are two matches when `xy==A`, `xy==B` and `xy==C`, so I sum the `y` values for each of these letters and get only one column for each letter. In contrast, because `xz` letters are all unique, summing simply returns the original values.

The closest I got was this:

```
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from=c(xy,xz), values_from=c(y,z), names_sep='.', values_fn=sum)
```

But this returns every combination

```
y.A.D y.A.E y.B.F y.B.G y.C.H y.C.I z.A.D z.A.E z.B.F z.B.G z.C.H z.C.I
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2     2     3     3     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something more elegant:

```
bind_rows(df %>% select(col = xy, y), df %>% select(col = xz, z)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-col, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, col), values_from = value, values_fn = sum)


# A tibble: 1 × 9
    y_A   y_B   y_C   z_D   z_E   z_F   z_G   z_H   z_I
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     7    11     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt for what it's worth...

```
df %>%
  summarise(name = list(c(xy, xz)),
            value = list(c(y, z)),
            label = list(rep(c("y", "z"), each = 6))) %>%
  unnest(c(name, value, label)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(label, name), names_sep = ".", values_fn = sum)
```

```
# A tibble: 1 × 9
    y.A   y.B   y.C   z.D   z.E   z.F   z.G   z.H   z.I
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     7    11     1     2     3     4     5     6
```